# Can the setup filename be derived from the executable file version number?

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to get Inno Setup to read the file version of the main executable file and set the name of the created setup to something like "myapp_setup_1_0_3708_19805.exe"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

(I haven't tried this recently but it certainly worked back in 2007 when I was using InnoSetup in this way. It might need some slight changes if Inno's syntax has changed since then.)

```
#define MainBinaryName  "MyMainFile.exe"
#define SetupBaseName   "setup_mytool_"
#define AppVersion      GetFileVersion(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + MainBinaryName)
#define AVF1            Copy(AppVersion, 1, Pos(".", AppVersion) - 1) + "_" + Copy(AppVersion, Pos(".", AppVersion) + 1)
#define AVF2            Copy(AVF1,       1, Pos(".", AVF1      ) - 1) + "_" + Copy(AVF1      , Pos(".", AVF1      ) + 1)
#define AppVersionFile  Copy(AVF2,       1, Pos(".", AVF2      ) - 1) + "_" + Copy(AVF2      , Pos(".", AVF2      ) + 1)

[Setup]
OutputBaseFilename={#SetupBaseName + AppVersionFile}
```

If MyMainFile.exe was version 1.2.3.4 then that should call the finished installer setup_mytool_1_2_3_4.exe

The AVF1, AVF2, etc. stuff is just there to replace the dots (.) in the version number with underscores (_) to avoid causing problems with things that can't cope with lots of dots in a filename.

Comment: beautiful! worked well, just needed the MainBinaryName in quotes :)  ( I edited your answer)

Comment: +1, I didn't know the preprocessor could be used for that. Will be removing my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
; Get the App Version from Main Program
; This Is Full App Version Major.Minor.Build.Revision
; Store First 3 Parts of Version in ShortAppVersion to be used for SBS Assembly Installation Major.Minor.Build
#dim Version[4]
#expr ParseVersion("MainProgram.exe", Version[0], Version[1], Version[2], Version[3])
#define AppVersion Str(Version[0]) + "." + Str(Version[1]) + "." + Str(Version[2]) + "." + Str(Version[3])
#define ShortAppVersion Str(Version[0]) + "." + Str(Version[1]) + "." + Str(Version[2])
```

Comment: perfect solution. thanks

Answer (score 2):

`GetFileVersion()` (described in other answers) returns a string of the form "Major.Minor.Rev.Build." If you want access to the individual elements so that you can format the string yourself (say, if you only want "Major.Minor" or "Major.Minor.Rev"), you can use the following approach from the [jrsoftware.innosetup mailing list](http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article//waArticleBookmark.6748325):

```
#define VerMajor
#define VerMinor
#define VerRev
#define VerBuild
#define FullVersion=ParseVersion('PathTo.exe', VerMajor, VerMinor, VerRev, VerBuild)
#define MyAppVersion = Str(VerMajor) + "." + Str(VerMinor)
```

Answer (score 1):

A much cleaner way of doing this involves using the `StringChange` function, which allows replacing the dots with something else:

```
#define MainBinaryName  "MyMainFile.exe"
#define SourcePath      "Path/To/File"
#define SetupBaseName   "setup_mytool_"
#define AppVersion      GetFileVersion(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + MainBinaryName)
#define AppVersionFile  StringChange(AppVersion, ".", "_")

[Setup]
OutputBaseFilename={#SetupBaseName + AppVersionFile}
```

Also, if you don't want to show all four version numbers (e.g. you want it to say `1.0.1` instead of `1.0.1.0`), you can replace the `AppVersion` line with the following:

```
#define NumberOfVersionPoints  3
#define AppVersion             Copy(GetFileVersion(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + MainBinaryName), 0, NumberOfVersionPoints * 2 - 1)
```

Comment: The code for `NumberOfVersionPoints` only works if the version number does not contain any two-digit elements (for example, "1.2.10.0" converts wrongly to "1.2.1").

Comment: @TypeIA Do you have an idea for how to handle that case?

Comment: I didn't at the time, but I found a solution on the Inno mailing list. I just posted a new answer below. Thanks for getting me started!