# How do I use "code" in Inno Setup's [Files] section?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to dynamically derive the source folder (and destination folder) for 32/64 bit installations. So how can I specify that in the [Files] section of Inno setup.
The following gives a compilation error:->

```
[Files]
Source: {#MySourcePath}\{code:GetSourceLibFolder}\*.jar; DestDir: {code:GetAppDir}\lib\;
```

I have the `GetSourceLibFolder()` and  `GetAppDir()` function defined in the code section.
The functions are very simple and just return a variable:

```
function GetSourceLibFolder(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result:= SourceLibFolder;
end;

function GetSourceBinFolder(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result:= SourceBinFolder;
end;
```

Thanks !

Comment: I am not sure whether we can call our codes from `[Code]` and use them in other places in InnoSetup script. How about using `#define` statement to create a string that applies your functions (just like in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329979/can-the-setup-filename-be-derived-from-the-executable-file-version-number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329979/can-the-setup-filename-be-derived-from-the-executable-file-version-number))

Comment: Where is this source lib folder: is it in the source folder relative to the base folder of your InnoSetup script? Why do you concern with the destination folder when you can just use `{app}`?  For example: let say your InnoSetup script file is in `.\ ` folder and your jar libraries are in `.\install\lib` and you want them to be in `lib` folder of your application folder `{app}`, you can define `Source: "install\lib\*.jar"; DestDir: "{app}\lib"` The easy way: you can have a separate InnoSetup script for each 32-bit and 64-bit setup by defining different source folder in each script file.

Comment: @eee: I want to have a single installer for 32 and 64 bit systems and so I have 2 different "lib" folders, viz. lib-32 and lib-64, which I set dynamically and hence want to read them dynamically.

Comment: InnoSetup allows you to pass user-defined variable from its command argument so you can use it to differentiate both lib folders, in Ant task example: `<exec executable="C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe"><arg value="${basedir}\application.iss"/><arg value="/dMyLibFolder=lib-32"/></exec>`. Then, in the script, you can use `{#MyLibFolder}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source path needs to be used at compile time (unless you have the `external` flag) which means you must use ISPP and a `#define`. The `[Code]` section is only for run/install time code so will work for the target path.

If you provide the code for your `GetSourceLibFolder` function, someone can convert it to ISPP.

Comment: Thanks ! I have edited my original post to include the function definition.

Comment: And again what is `SourceLibFolder`? remember it needs to be got at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: `SourceLibFolder` is a global variable that gets it value in the code section of `DefaultDestDir` variable in the `[Setup]` section:         `DefaultDirName={code:SetProgramFileLocation}\HP\Pulse\{#MyAppName}`